# Omit zeros before the decimal point and convert scientific notation in siunitx/pgfmath

Tags: formatting, siunitx, pgfmath

I'm trying to automatically format numbers in a way that doesn't convert say .8 to 0.8 while at the same time scientific notation is converted to exponent-free notation. `siunitx` seems to be able to do both but I don't get it to work together.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\myround}[1]{\num[zero-decimal-to-integer,scientific-notation=fixed,fixed-exponent=0,round-mode=places,round-precision=2,add-integer-zero=false]{#1}}
%\newcommand{\myround}[1]{\num[zero-decimal-to-integer,round-mode=places,round-precision=2,add-integer-zero=false]{#1}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\myround{.8}
\myround{1}
\myround{4.00000000001}
\myround{-.1151}
\myround{4.44089209850063E-16}

.80
1
4
-.12
0
\end{document}
```

The first `\newcommand` in this MWE IMHO *should* produce the right result because it got all the right options. However, the zeros before the decimal point are added back in:

[image: zeros still there]

Using the second macro definition (that is commented out) yields this result, proving that in principle it should work but of course the scientific notation isn't converted and not rounded properly either (rounding to two decimal places, 4.44×10<sup>-16</sup> should be 0.00×10<sup>0</sup> if anything).

[image: scientific notation still there]

I also added the `pgfmath` tag because `\pgfmathprintnumber` seems to have much of the same options as `\num` from `siunitx` and I don't know if one uses the other internally and I also wouldn't mind to use that other if it does what I need.

Comment: Have a look at the `numprint` package!

Comment: The scientific notation doesn’t allow `.80` (or `0.80` for that matter). PGF’s math printing number and `siunitx` are independent (though you can send `siunitx`’ settings to PGF).

Comment: @Jake Sorry I didn't make that clear: the second line *is* the desired output.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Good to know. The thing is, I don't want scientific notation but I occasionally get it on the input side and to get rid of it I need those options.

Comment: @Christian: Ah yes, okay. The problem seems to be that if you use rounding in `siunitx`, it loses track of whether you had a leading zero in your input or not, and assumes you did. I guess this is a bug / feature request?

Comment: @Jake Except for the minus sign. That was just my stupidity and blindness of not being in math mode and not noticing it.

Comment: @Jake Maybe it is a bug, yes `:/` But rounding as such works fine with omitting the zeros as can be seen in the second example. It's really just the scientific notation conversion that adds the zeros.

Comment: @KeksDose Thanks for the hint. The syntax seems very different. If you're familiar with it and can quickly rewrite the `\newcommand` to produce the desired output, I'd gladly accept that as an answer.

Comment: @Jake No, your answer was actually ok as far as I could see before you deleted it. I just mimicked the behaviour of `siunitx` as far as it didn't bother me but both .8 and 4.00 would be ok as output.

Comment: I don't think it's good practice to omit the zero.

Comment: @egreg Typographically, I couldn't agree more. I hate it. However, it is not only good practice but *the* practice in at least part of the social sciences.

Comment: The current `siunitx` code works such that the two operations here are entirely separate. Forcing a fixed exponent is set up such that the output _must_ have an integer part even if it's zero. I can of course look to alter this behaviour: the problem is getting the 'expected' interactions correct.

Comment: @JosephWright I don't know how many other interactions there might be but in this case it might be easiest if you just separated the conversion *from* scientific notation and the conversion *to* scientific notation. The problem here seems to be that it's not possible to convert the scientific input to the desired output because the conversion requires scientific output itself.

Comment: @Christian The primary aim of `siunitx` is formatting units: the number code has always been there to _support_ that primary aim. However, people do seem to want very challenging numerical handling! I certainly do my best, but of course this is a learning experience for me: what other people feel is 'standard' is sometimes very different to what I'm used to. I will of course add this request to the list: I need to rework various internals (again) to allow even more flexibility for numbers.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks but at least for me you don't need to do that. You could just put what you just said into the documentation and maybe link to `pgfmath` for more advanced stuff. Only problem might be that the two are not 100% compatible. For example `pgfmath` doesn't seem to be able to use the surrounding text font and it doesn't have a `round-minimum` feature AFAICS. But well, maybe it's the best thing to implement these things there instead of bloating `siunitx` if number formatting never was the primary goal of the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\pgfmathprintnumber` can do this if you specify `skip 0.` and `fixed`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\myround}[1]{\pgfmathprintnumber[skip 0.,fixed]{#1}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\myround{.8}
\myround{1}
\myround{4.00000000001}
\myround{-.1151}
\myround{4.44089209850063E-16}

.80
1
4
-.12
0
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, thanks! If you know a way to set the numbers in the surrounding font instead of always in math font, that would be perfect. If not I have to change the parts where I still have to use `siunitx` because I use actual units and go through my document if I somewhere still use numbers without any surrounding macro.

Comment: @Christian: No, sorry, I don't know how to do that off the top of my head. It's probably best if you open a new question for this along with an example document.

Comment: I guess just fixing my document is easier. I forgot to mention that I did find `assume math mode=true` which switches off `ensuremath` but that doesn't seem like the right way accomplish that. Anyway, as I said, this will do just fine. Thanks!