# Omit zeros before the decimal point when printing coordinates near nodes in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

I would like to omit leading zeroes (i.e. before the decimal point) to have the numbers avoid overlap. It would also satisfy APA style, since the values fall always in the range of [0-1]. This is what I have right now:

[image]

with the following latex code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 1.1*\columnwidth,
        height = 8cm,
        ybar=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=0.25,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        bar width=12pt,
        symbolic x coords={Recall, Precision, F$_1$},
        xtick = data, ymin=0, ymax=0.1,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style = {
            anchor=south,
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            precision=2,
        }
    ]
        \addplot[style={fill=bblue}]
            coordinates {(Recall,.057) (Precision,.007) (F$_1$,.014)};

        \addplot[style={fill=rred}]
            coordinates {(Recall,.057) (Precision,.005) (F$_1$,.009)};

        \addplot[style={fill=ggreen}]
            coordinates {(Recall,.091) (Precision,.008) (F$_1$,.015)};

        \addplot[style={fill=ppurple}]
            coordinates {(Recall,0) (Precision,0) (F$_1$,0)};
        
        \addplot[style={fill=yyellow}]
            coordinates {(Recall,.023) (Precision,.004) (F$_1$,.007)};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102154 @Jake provides a solution for this problem when simply printing numbers anywhere in text, but when I try these solutions in the settings of my tikzpicture, I obtain some errors.

I tried adding the `skip 0.` setting to the axis options to no avail. If anyone would happen to know how to add this setting it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to tex.SE. Thank you for question, which is posed already quite well. If you want to improve the quality of question further, i.e. make it easier for people to help you, you could turn your code into a compilable minimal working example by adding a `documentclass` (such as `standalone`) and the required packages (and only those). Then people can just copy and paste your code and start working on an answer rather than having to figure out what packages your are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why `skip 0.` did not work for you. I used the following code and the output looks like expected:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 1.1*\columnwidth,
        height = 8cm,
        ybar=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=0.25,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        bar width=12pt,
        symbolic x coords={Recall, Precision, F$_1$},
        xtick = data, ymin=0, ymax=0.1,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,/pgf/number format/precision=2},
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style = {
            anchor=south,
            font=\footnotesize,
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
            /pgf/number format/precision=2,
            skip 0.
        }
        ]
        \addplot[style={fill=blue}]   coordinates {(Recall,.057) (Precision,.007) (F$_1$,.014)};
        \addplot[style={fill=red}]    coordinates {(Recall,.057) (Precision,.005) (F$_1$,.009)};
        \addplot[style={fill=green}]  coordinates {(Recall,.091) (Precision,.008) (F$_1$,.015)};
        \addplot[style={fill=purple}] coordinates {(Recall,.00) (Precision,0) (F$_1$,0)};
        \addplot[style={fill=yellow}] coordinates {(Recall,.023) (Precision,.004) (F$_1$,.007)};
        
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

I took the liberty of changing your `ytick` labels to be more uniform and the font size of the `nodes near coords` to fit on top of your bars.

Note: If you want to appear the `0` values as `0` and not `.00` then remove the line `/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,`.

Comment: Thank you! 

I think it might have had something to do with my cached build files (the .aux files, etc.) since I was still getting errors with what you responded until I removed those and built from nothing.